# Check a continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity

I need to check the continuity of thos function:

$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^3,  &x\in\Bbb Q \\
0, & x\notin\Bbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
that is what i have done so far Let $x_{0}=\frac{p}{q}\ p\in\Bbb Z\ and\  q\in\Bbb N\ (p,q)coprime$  then we have $f(x_{0})=x^3$ $\\ \ \ \  $Let $a\notin\Bbb Q$ be any irrational number and define $x_{n}=x_{0}+\frac{a}{n}$ $n\in\Bbb N\ \  $ So we have $f(x_{n})=0\ \ \ $This implies $\vert x_{0}-x_{n}\vert = \frac{a}{n}\ \ \ $ and also $\vert f(x_{0})-f(x_{n})\vert = x^3\ \ \ $ Now we will take $n=1+[\frac{a}{\delta}] ([x]\ $is the ceiling function) so we have $$\vert x_{0}-x_{n}\vert = \frac{a}{1+[\frac{a}{\delta}]}<\frac{a}{[\frac{a}{\delta}]}\le\delta$$ But we alsso have $\vert f(x_{0})-f(x_{n})\vert = x^3>\epsilon\ \ $ The proof is the same for the irrationals as well therefore the function (f) is discontinuous on every $x\not = 0$
for x=0 we have
$\vert x_{0}-0\vert =\vert x\vert <\delta\ \ $ Let $\delta =\sqrt[3]\epsilon\ \ $ Thus implies $\vert f(x_{0}-f(0)\vert = \vert x^3-0\vert<\delta^3=\epsilon$
$\vert f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})=\vert 0-0\vert = 0<\epsilon\ \ $ Therefore the function is continuous on $x=0$
Im new the concept of continuity so I just want to know if my proof holds and if not what was my mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't easier to use the following:

> For any real number $r$, there exists a sequence $a_n$ of rationals numbers such that $a_n\rightarrow x$ and a sequence of irrational numbers $b_n$ such that $b_n\rightarrow x$.

and

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $x\in \mathbb{R}$ if for all sequences $x_n\rightarrow x$ we have that $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.

Now let $r \in \mathbb{R}_0$, then $(a_n)^3=f(a_n)\rightarrow r^3$ and $0=f(b_n)\rightarrow 0$. This shows that $f$ is discontinuous everywhere except maybe in zero. Can you figure out what happens in zero?

Comment: Yeah it's much easier this way, like I said I'm new to this concept but thank you

Comment: No worries, epsilon-delta is not always the way to go.